# How do I access "this" from an external class in Javascript / "this" binding

Tags: javascript

I have an external javascript class that accepts a callback method parameter.  When the callback is run, it is like the API steals the method and tries to run within itself.

I have an example below.  The idea is the API should be able to announce the manager to be "Manager" but instead it announces itself("API").

```js
class Manager{
  constructor(){
    this.name = "Manager";
  }
  
  manage(){
    var api = new API(this.announce);
  }
  
  announce(){
    alert(this.name);
  }
}

class API{
  constructor(announceCallback){
    this.name = "API";
    this.announceManager = announceCallback;
    this.announceManager();
  }
}

manager = new Manager();
manager.manage();
```

How do I access "this" from an external class in Javascript.  I have read that [JS can lose implicit binding](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#implicitly-lost).  I've also been reading about [call() and apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), but these appear to only work with functions and not class methods.  How can I modify my "Manager" class so when API calls the "announceCallback" it alerts "Manager" rather than "API".  I'm specifically needing resolution for use in a class and [not independent functions as described in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

Comment: tl;dr: `new API(this.announce.bind(this))`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment SOLVED.  I read the other post previously but wasn't clear how any distinction with classes rather than independent functions.

Comment: Class methods are functions too. There is no difference.